# Configuring Global Toolbar on Siebel CRM

Tags: siebel

I have a requirement to remove some Global Tool Bar Item such as Apply Target List and Save Target List on Siebel CRM. Other Toolbar such as sitemap and query should stay.

But I cant figure the configuration. I have tried the following Object Definitions 
1. Menu 
2. Toolbar 
3. Class.

I can't find Apply target list and Save Target List.

Although I did find apply target list and save target list under
Menu> Generic Web> Menu Items object definition.
I inactivated and compiled.

But the two Icons still appear on the Global tool bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under Toolbar->HIMain-> ApplyTargetList & SaveTargetList are items. Did you try disabling them ?

Also , please look under Class [CSSSWEFrameList]

If you still cannot remove the Items and are using OpenUI, it could be possible to add a simple CSS rule to hide the entry in the menu list.

Comment: Please was your email